# Laravel validating socialite token in every request

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite

I am creating laravel API based application where I used passport for authentication. I have also used the laravel socialite for social media login. The things are working fine with laravel passport but I am unable to verify the social medea token, Like we pass the google token in the header of every request but not getting the way to check the token validity in every request.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check on middleware:

Middleware File:

```
class ApiAuthenticate {    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $status = false;
        $accessToken = $request->header('AccessToken');
        if($accessToken) {
            $user_check = User::where("api_token", $accessToken)->first();
            if(count($user_check) > 0) 
            {              
               $status = true;
            }
        }

        if($status == false) {
            return response()->json([
                'code' => 401,
                'msg' => trans('web_service.unathenticated')
            ]);
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Route File:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'api'), function()
{
    Route::get('/users', 'Api\UsersController@getUser');
    Route::post('/users/save', 'Api\UsersController@saveUser'); 

})
```

Comment: How do we add two middleware as the passport middleware is already is in use?
Like:
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::put('assignments/{assignment}','AssignmentsController@update');
});

Comment: Ok, Then check $accessToken = $request->header('AccessToken');